# is it possible to trigger pom.xml using team city tool?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

is it possible to trigger pom.xml using team city tool?

I have selenium maven project using java and want to use team city... is there any way to use team city tool to trigger maven pom.xml file.

please help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer Documentation : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Maven

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Maven+Server-Side+Settings